# Java Elasticsearch BoolQueryBuilder for multiple fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

The index is having 20 fields. I am having one search value received as query parameter in api.

There are 3 fields in index `name`, `city`, `state`
In my spring boot application, I need to return response if the search value say `new` matches with any of the 3 fields.

`Like return the response : city=="new" || state=="new" || name=="new"`

What BoolQuery I should write for that ? Or any other way for it. I am using `RestHighLevelClient` of `elastic search 7.7`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using should query. Must is like more AND logic and should is like an OR.

```
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", searchValue)); 
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("city", searchValue)); 
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("state", searchValue));
```

minimum_should_match is also worth reading.

[Elastic search boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)